# Friends are constantly visiting and friends constantly visit

Tags: tense, difference

I am not native English speaker and new to English. Please let me know what is the difference between below sentences and which one is correct.

> 1. His friends **are constantly visiting** him.
> 2. His friends **constantly visit** him.

Comment: I read first sentence in a letter that is being written to request for room change. First line is the reason to change share accommodation. Can we write same reason as line 2. If not why?